# Send data to PHP with ajax using formdata

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

SOLUTION: I had to drop the sumbmit button and use a regular button. The rest of this code works. I also dropped the HTML form.

I'm trying to send an image + some text to my php script with ajax using formdata.
This is what i got:

```
$ajax_uploadImage = function (form)
{
    var data = new FormData();

    data.append('title', form.find('#title').val());
    data.append('comment', form.find('#comment').val());
    data.append('image', form.find('#image').prop('files')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '../php/upload_image.php',
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('something');
        }
    });
}
```

The form in the function parameters is a normal html form, here is the form in html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_image">
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" />
    <br />

    <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
    <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" />
    <br />

    <label for="image">Image:</label>
    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" />
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload picture" name="submit">
    <hr />
</form>
```

The alert in success never triggers, can anyone help?

EDIT: Adding the PHP, even though it doesn't do anything:

```
<?php echo 'something'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are storing a jQuery object in the `FormData` which cannot work. Use the values of those elements instead. In case of the file input you need to use the `File` object in the `files` property of the DOM element:

```
data.append('title', form.find('#title').val());
data.append('comment', form.find('#comment').val());
data.append('image', form.find('#image').prop('files')[0]);
```

Comment: I've added your changes, but I still dont get a result. I now try to use an alert in success, but it does not trigger. I've added my PHP, but it does not do much.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding form action like:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_image" action="upload_image.php">
```

Comment: If I use "file" I get an exception saying:
Cannot read property "0" of undefined.

Comment: Also can you post the upload_image.php file, a sample should look like: `try foreach ($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key => $error) {  
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {  
            $name = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key];  
            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key], "uploads/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$key]);  
        }  
    }`

Comment: If I use the action attribute the site redirects me to action.php, which I do not want. It shouldn't have to be there either.
Also, the php file is at the bottom of the opening post, thats all it does atm. If I just can access it though the $_FILES object I know the rest of the logic I have works.

Comment: ok, can you post the full code you are using somewhere? maybe [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ... It'd be easier to debug that way...

Comment: I just discovered that if I set a breakpoint after I've sent the xhr object and then start it again, it works. Seems like it needs a little bit of time to reach the server script and be returned.. perhaps it is because the whole page refreshes after I've pressed submit.